# Sending Array when using window.open

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I tried to do this

```
var new_win= window.open("print.php","Print","toolbar=no,width=960,height=860);
new_win.values=inputs;
```

Where inputs is an array, in the print.php page, I used this array, it works fine for me on firefox and chrome, but in IE 11 it says values is undefined. What's wrong? and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you're trying to read `.values` before you've filled it?

Comment: no it is filled, and as I said it works fine on mozilla and chrome

Comment: Different browsers may have different timings. This Hail Mary approach to passing data is bounding to give you timing problems. It would be prudent to wait for a `ready` or `load` event at least.

Comment: is there another way to pass data??

Comment: There are many ways to pass data to another window. You can pass it as part of a `GET` request, you can use `postMessage` and you can make a custom messaging system.